# Google Responsive DFP Tags not working with Ad sense

Tags: responsive-design, adsense, google-dfp

I am trying to get DFP tags to work responsively with adsense.  However, when I push to a testing environment I cannot regularly generate ads on mobile devices.  Sometimes it works but most of the time I just get a blank empty div.  I used the exact same solution but with hard coded banners and everything works fine so I suspect this has something to do with the DFP -> ad sense connection.  I am using DFP SB and below are the mapping/define slot.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

```
var mappingRectangle = googletag.sizeMapping().

  addSize([450, 800], [336, 280]).   
  addSize([340, 550], [320, 100]).
  addSize([0, 0], [234, 60]).

  build();



googletag.defineSlot('/XXXXXXX/LT_Gallery_Responsive_Rectangle_ATF', [[234,60],[320, 100], [336, 280]], 'div-gpt-ad-1420660773974-0').defineSizeMapping(mappingRectangle).addService(googletag.pubads());
```